# How to configure Chrome to automatically fix URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, url

I am using URL Fixer add-on in Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/url-fixer/) which automatically corrects the URLs, if I mistype them. How do I set up Chrome to act like that>

Answer (score 3):

#### Do not use URL fixer

This is not the answer you were looking for but I want to warn you.

On Amazon sites, this add-on will replace the referral-ID ([affiliate ID](http://designpx.com/business/short-amazon-affiliate-links/)) to the developer ones.
The pattern is `tag=(their id)-20`.  Every time you buy something on Amazon, he gets a small amount of money with your purchase.

---

#### You don't believe it?

1. Download [URL Fixer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/url-fixer/) with Chrome, IE or Opera to get its source files directly
2. Extract the .XPI file with 7-Zip, WinRAR or any other extractor
3. Go to `..\defaults\rules.json` and open the file with Notepad
4. Search for *Amazon*. You will find the following code at the very end of the last line

   ```
   "domainReferrals":{"amazon.co.uk":"tag=uf07d-21","amazon.com":"tag=uf024-20","amazon.de":"tag=uf0e6-21","amazon.es":"tag=uf07-21","amazon.fr":"tag=uf02b-21","amazon.it":"tag=uf08d-21","ozon.ru":"partner=urlfixer"}
   ```

   Guess what this line does? These are the developers ref-IDs which are appended.
   Additionally the ref-ID in your amazon session cookie gets overwritten too.

---

#### Now the story gets big

There is a connection between *URL fixer* and the commonly used addon *Adblock Plus*. Remember, this small amount of referral money can get very high if thousands of people use the add-on.

Until 28-Jun-2013 both add-ons (same developer) were using the same technique to replace ref-IDs. They quickly removed it from Adblock Plus after it was revealed. But have a look at Adblock Plus' [source code change](https://hg.adblockplus.org/adblockplus/rev/451343f1ddc3) and search for the following line.

```
loadRulesFrom("http://urlfixer.org/download/rules.json?version=" + RULES_VERSION, false, function(success)
```

Comment: Even if they are getting something it does not bother me as they must have put some effort to make the addon. But they should inform the users before hand and must not do secretly.

Comment: @RichaGoyal Yeah, I agree. And I'm sorry that I can't help you further with your initial issue.